Compile ROS2 from source on a Raspberry Pi (raspbian): how to pass `-latomic` flag correctly?
I'm trying to compile ROS 2 (ros_base) on a Raspberry Pi running some 32bit Raspbian "bullseye" (some RevPi device with the factory installed image, armhf architecture). I know that the recommended approach is to install an OS with Tier 1 support or flash a 64bit OS and use Docker containers (https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Installing-on-Raspberry-Pi.html). I thought, I'd try this build first, before I'll flash a new image.
I'm having difficulties with the linker error related to -latomic not being found (so far with rcutils and rclcpp packages). I found this is a common problem with raspbian, which can be addressed by passing the additional linker flag via cmake flags.

https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/issues/171#issuecomment-1126641848
https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/issues/171#issuecomment-1123243641

This is the exact build command I used. (The sequential, single threaded build is used because of the little RAM the system has. This doesn't seem to be related to the linker error, though.)
MAKEFLAGS=-j1 colcon build --cmake-args "-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS='-latomic'" "-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS='-latomic'" --executor sequential

But when I do this, the flag seems to be added at the front of the command (noticed when checking the build config). The first package that would error out would be rcutils.
Example:
CMakeFiles/test_split.dir/link.txt:/usr/bin/c++  -std=c++14 -latomic CMakeFiles/test_split.dir/test/test_split.cpp.o -o test_split  -Wl,-rpath,/home/pi/ros/humble/build/rcutils gtest/libgtest_main.a gtest/libgtest.a librcutils.so /home/pi/ros/humble/install/mimick_vendor/lib/libmimick.a -pthread -ldl 

When run like this, the error still occurs. I need to run the command with the linker flag at the end, like this:
CMakeFiles/test_split.dir/link.txt:/usr/bin/c++  -std=c++14 CMakeFiles/test_split.dir/test/test_split.cpp.o -o test_split  -Wl,-rpath,/home/pi/ros/humble/build/rcutils gtest/libgtest_main.a gtest/libgtest.a librcutils.so /home/pi/ros/humble/install/mimick_vendor/lib/libmimick.a -pthread -ldl -latomic 

Am I doing anything wrong with the colcon configuration? Can I adust the config, to make the flag to be added last?

Please edit your question to explain how to reproduce your error and what you're doing to inject the argument. It's hard to give a suggestion how to fix it without knowing what you're doing to start.

I added the exact build command I used. The sequential, single threaded build is used because of the little RAM the system has. This doesn't seem to be related to the linker error, though. In order to really reproduce the issue you would probably need a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian OS, as the linker flag seems to be normally not required.

I think this Q&A might be related (link libraries need to follow object files in the command line). The question would be, how to tell colcon the flags should go to the end of the compiler command, and not to the front? Or if this is, how it is supposed to be: why doesn't this work as intended here?

FWIW: I just flashed the arm64 image that is available by the vendor. Now I can just use the binary distribution in a docker container.

Don't do this. Just flash the arm64 image that is available by the vendor. Then you can use the ROS 2 binary distribution in a docker container (because Tier 1 support).
Not sure why the cmake flag ends up at the position it does, but I feel this is a separate, unrelated issue.
